# Is there a way to modify a Gurobi parameter (MIPFOCUS) in a Pyomo environment?

Tags: optimization, parameters, pyomo, gurobi

I'm relatively new in Pyomo and Gurobi. I'm trying to solve a Non-Convex quadratic programming but the solver output give me the following issue:
"gurobipy.GurobiError: Quadratic equality constraints are non-convex. Set NonConvex parameter to 2 to solve model."
So, I'm trying to modify the solver parameter in order to obtain the correct result.

p.s. I'm already tryed to install gurobipy but the package manager Pip give me: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gurobipy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gurobipy"

Tanks a lot for your time and consideration!

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here. Did you manage to install Gurobi or not? Do you need Pyomo or do you rather want to use Gurobi directly?

Answer (score 1):

This page explains how to set parameters in Pyomo: https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_models.html#sending-options-to-the-solver

```
optimizer.options["NonConvex"] = 2
```

or

```
results = optimizer.solve(instance, options="NonConvex=2")
```